# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have

```
hd.meta(http-equiv='Content-Type', content='text/html;charset=UTF-8')
```

And I am getting:

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Why so ?

Comment: `http-equiv` -- the highphen? I'm not a python expert, I am just unsure if that is valid syntax.

Comment: What library is this? I agree: not being a Python user but it doesn't look like the usual syntax to me either.

Comment: `http-equiv` is of course valid syntax for an expression—but, as the error says, an expression isn't a valid keyword. Only identifiers can be keywords. Whatever function `hd.meta` is, it can't be expecting you to pass it invalid keywords; the docs presumably tell you how to actually use it in this case (maybe `http_equiv`, or maybe by passing a dict instead of a set of keywords, or who knows what), but without knowing what function this is or where it comes from, nobody can give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Misandrist already pointed out, `http-equiv` is interpreted as a subtraction like this: `http - equiv`.

If you still need to pass the data to this function, you can do the following thing:

```
dct = {
       'http-equiv': 'Content-Type',
       'content': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'
}
hd.meta(**dct)
```

Put the keyword arguments into a dictionary and pass its expansion (`**dct`).

Answer (score 7):

I think `http-equiv` is being parsed as `http` minus `equiv`. You should try `http_equiv`, or possibly use a special argument depending on the API.